# this extension is not installable on any installed products nuget

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to get facebook login in c# for windows phone 7.
For that I need package manager console. I downloaded nuget package manager. But I am getting following  error `This extension is not installable on any installed products`.
Help me to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have visual studio installed? NuGet package manager requires visual studio to be installed, as it's an extension of it.

Comment: Ya i have vs 2010 express installed. still I am not able to.

Comment: Where did you download the nuget VSIX? Please make sure it's for VS 2010/2012. We have separate VSIXes for VS 2012/2012 versus. VS 2013.